# Install Apache Zeppelin binary on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to install Apache Zeppelin and various interpreters on Ubuntu Linux using AWS EC2. Below are my steps for the binary and from source.

SSH through Putty as ubuntu@IP

```
wget http://mirrors.gigenet.com/apache/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.6.2/zeppelin-0.6.2.tgz
sudo tar -zxf zeppelin-0.6.2.tgz
cd zeppelin-0.6.2
sudo bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

It gives me the following status in the cli:

```
Zeppelin start [OK]
Zeppelin process died [FAILED]
```

I then tried to install build from source using the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig
git clone https://github.com/apache/zeppelin.git
apt-cache search maven
sudo apt-get install maven
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
mvn -version
```

I use the java home directory and set the environment variable for JAVA_HOME by

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre

cd into zeppelin folder and then run

mvn clean package -Pspark-2.0 -Phadoop-2.4 -Pyarn -Ppyspark -Psparkr -Pscala-2.11
```

And it builds Zeppelin but fails at the next Zeppelin: Interpreter

How do I get her to work without going to AWS EMR? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tgz file that you downloaded is source file. Not prebuild one. So you need to build it first before you try to start Zeppelin daemone. If you won't modify the source, I'd recommend you to download binary package.

```
$ http://mirrors.gigenet.com/apache/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.6.2/zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all.tgz
$ sudo tar -zxf zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all.tgz
$ cd zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all
$ sudo bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

Then you can start Zeppelin server without any further steps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. To be overly thorough for others, I added wget before the first step and it worked perfectly.